# How can you send the same text to multiple people without it being a group message?

Tags: iphone, jailbreak, messages

I want to send "Happy Thanksgiving!" to 35 different people, but I do not want it to be treated as a group message. How can this be accomplished on the iPhone 4S (with or without jailbreak applications, such as biteSMS) with iOS 5.1.1?

The reasons that I would not want it treated as a group message are:

- I do not want the recipients to see the numbers of other recipients
- I do not want the recipients' replies to go to multiple people
- I do not want the recipients' replies to be grouped in a group message, but to instead be part of each individual thread
- depending on the message, I may specifically not want a given recipient to know that other recipients received the same message.

Optimally, the solution would also allow pictures to be attached and would automatically send iMessages instead of text messages to iOS users - but those parts are less important than being able to send plain text messages.

Comment: Have you tried changing `Settings > Messages > Group Messaging` to off? If this solves your problem, I'll convert it into an answer.

Comment: I had not tried that. I've tested it out a little and it seems to work. I'll test it out more and give you an update.

Comment: That's good to hear.

Comment: Okay, that seems to work :) It's a bit unwieldy, of course, but I imagine I can find an SBSettings toggle or something.

Comment: You could always make your own SBSettings toggle.

Comment: Also, group messages to Google Voice contacts are silently dropped, because GV doesn't accept MMS.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The option you're looking for is located at `Settings > Messages > Group Messaging`. Turning this off will send all messages individually to their recipients.

Note: Disabling MMS Messaging will remove the Group Messaging toggle from the list.

Note: Some cellular service providers do not support Group Messaging, so if you have MMS enabled, and you still don't see Group Messaging, then it's likely that your provider does not support it. From Apple: [If you don't see an option to turn on MMS Messaging or Group Messaging on your iPhone, contact your carrier.](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202724)

[image]

Comment: I don't have a Settings> Messages > Group Messaging option on my iPhone 4s. How do I turn it off?

Comment: I don't have the option either, maybe it depends on the carrier. Can you add a screenshot to the answer to make it clear at least what you are looking at here?

Comment: I have an iPhone4 iOS 7.1.2 my carrier is Vodafone New Zealand, and I don't have this option.

Comment: @patrix Do you have MMS disabled? I added a note about it after you all had mentioned that you don't see it, but forgot to ask you.

Comment: I usually do. But even if I enable MMS and close/reopen settings I don't get a Group Messaging option (iOS 9)

Comment: I'm guessing it's Provider-related. I don't have it either, iPhone 6S, iOS 9.3.5, Carrier O2, UK.

Comment: @Tetsujin That seams to be the consensus. I'll add it to my answer.

Comment: @Tetsujin Checked Apple's support website, and sure enough, they say that it's up to the carrier to support it.

Comment: Nice Ubuntu font.

Comment: I'm assuming there's no way to do this for an individual message?

Comment: @StevenVascellaro Correct, as far as I know.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a Mac you can use https://porterhouse.app which lets you do that with a single click, and sends as iMessage to iOS users too