# How to text, as a blind carbon copy, multiple phone numbers at once?

Tags: iphone, jailbreak, messages

http://ipod.about.com/od/phonefeatures/ht/multi_sms_iph.htm explains as it claims in its title: 'How To Send Text Messages to Multiple Recipients Using iPhone'. However, what do I do if I want to prevent each recipients from seeing all the other recipients in the address field (ie I want this to be a Blind Carbon Copy)? 
For my iPhone 5s, I already tried https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/75554, which claims:

> The option you're looking for is located at `Settings > Messages > Group Messaging.` Turning this off will send all messages individually to their recipients.

I do see and can access (iPhone  Home Screen) > `Settings > Messages`, but just like the commenters below that answer, I can't find `Group Messaging`?

Comment: I don't see it either, iOS 8. That previous post was back in iOS 5 & 6 days, maybe it disappeared since, or maybe it is carrier/network dependent.

Comment: What is your carrier? On AT&T it shows up for me.

Comment: on AT&T and iOS 8.1.2 I do see the option for "Group messages" although I've never played with it and don't know what it actually controls.  I also not that if you Turn off the "MMS Messaging" option right above it, the "group messaging" switch is removed or disappears.

Comment: I updated my answer on the question you linked to. http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/75554/18387